# Unable to ping hosted website from virtual Ubuntu host

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, nginx

The setup:
Got a virtual machine running Ubuntu 16.04. On that virtual machine I'm also running a VPN service and `nginx` webserver. I'm also using a bridged adapter.

I'm able to access the webserver from my domain name on internet and locally on the VM IP.

The problem:
I am now trying to use Let's Encrypt in order to create an SSL certificate. But it fails claiming it cannot reach the webserver using the domain name. I cannot ping the domain name either, nor the public IP mapped to the domain name from the VM. I can ping it from the Windows host.

```
sudo letsencrypt certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html -d domain.se -d srv01.domain.se Failed authorization procedure. domain.se (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Could not connect to domain.se, srv01.domain.se (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Could not connect to srv01.domain.se
```

Let me know if you need more information I'd be glad to provide logs or any other information if necessary.

Comment: sudo letsencrypt certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html -d domain.se -d srv01.domain.se
Failed authorization procedure. domain.se (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Could not connect to domain.se, srv01.domain.se (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Could not connect to srv01.domain.se

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that the web server on the guest system is reachable from public internet? Is there any firewall or port forwarding in place? Afaik Let's Encrypt starts its own little internet service on some non-standard port for the domain verification.

Comment: Hi David! Thanks for the reply. You understood me 100% correct. Yes, I have portforwarded the relevant ports 443, and port 80 in my local GW. I'm unable to port forward using my VPN. So the web requests passes my local GW into my guest. I think you're right in that. Would've been good to know which ports it uses for that purpose. Any clue?

Comment: Update: Oops, the site isn't accessible from the internet apparently. Only locally. Will continue troubleshooting.

Comment: Okay, so I can reach my webserver locally using the domain name. But I cannot for the life of me figure out why it isn't accessible from the internet. Any help would be greatly rewarded with cyber kisses.

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect that so other people can see that right away. I don't know much about VM networking and web server configuration.